# jQuery UI Dialog on resizing shrinks the content of the Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen a strange behavior of **jQuery UI** [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and I am not able to understand:

1. What the issue is? or
2. What am I doing wrong here? or
3. Is this a known bug?

Steps followed to replicate the issue:

1. Open the jQuery UI dialog by clicking on the New / More buttons.
2. Then try re-sizing the dialog vertically.
3. You will see the abnormality that width of the dialog's content decreases automatically, making a scrollbar to appear inside the dialog.

**EDIT:** I see that if I remove twitter bootstrap from the page then the issue still appears but is not much noticeable. whatever be the reason I cannot remove twitter bootstrap from my page because it is being used in all other places in my current project.

> **Before re-sizing**

[image: Before re-sizing]

> **After re-sizing**

[image: After re-sizing vertically the width shrinks automatically]

Here is my jQuery code. Please check the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/khurram_khu/ujqnatw7/8/):

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnNew", function () {
    $("#popOutNewFolder").dialog({
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        modal: true
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "#btnMore", function () {
    $("#popOutMoreFolder").dialog({
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Comment: this bug will in the latest version jQuery UI 1.12.1 i would of thought they would have corrected this by now??? after more than 2 years im guessing several, but what i dont get is i know they have revamped the dialog since then so.. am i missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the tickets #8506 and #9832, it is mentioned, that the bug has to do with different `box-sizing` set. Obviously the calculation of the dialog/content doesn't work right if the dialog container or the dialog content are not `box-sizing: content-box`. 
Best solution for me was adding this to the css:

```
.ui-dialog, .ui-dialog-content {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujqnatw7/28/) with this fix.

Comment: I like your solution... Short and simple. Thanks.

Comment: content still shrink when resizing.

Answer (score 6):

I did some more research and found out that this is a known bug *(jQuery UI Team knows about the bug)*. And they have several Tickets assigned to this bug.
If you want to follow their bug tracking then look here:

1. [Ticket #8506](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8506)
2. [Ticket #9832](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9832)
3. [Ticket #10069](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10069)

---

I found a workaround until they *(jQuery UI Team)* find a solution to the bug.
Workaround is to make use of `resizeStop` event of the Dialog while initializing the dialog. So the code would look like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnNew", function () {
    $("#popOutNewFolder").dialog({
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        modal: true,
        resizeStop: myResize
    });
});

$(document).on("click", "#btnMore", function () {
    $("#popOutMoreFolder").dialog({
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        modal: true,
        resizeStop: myResize
    });
});

function myResize(event, ui) {
    $(this).height($(this).parent().height() - $(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').height() - 34);
    $(this).width($(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').width() + 2);
}
```

**EDIT** (28th Aug 2018):
I found @Dev-iGi's solution to be better. So marking it as an answer. I updated my solution to include his. Check here: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/khurram_khu/ujqnatw7/)

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to use a hardcoded number of pixels (like `- 34` in another answer) because that's just never a good idea. At some point, it'll be a different size (maybe using a different theme) and the fix will not work anymore.
The [answer with the CSS fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34395499/4621186) didn't work right in my case but gave me the right hint.

So here's another "fix"/workaround that's simple:

```
//Resize handler for broken Dialog
function fixDialogWidth(event, ui)
{
    var $dialog = $(event.target);
    var $content = $dialog.closest(".ui-dialog-content");
    $content.css("width", "100%");
}

//Create Dialog
$caller.dialog({
    resize: fixDialogWidth,
});
```

Or inline:

```
//Create Dialog
$caller.dialog({
    resize: function() {
        $(this).closest(".ui-dialog-content").
        css("width", "100%");
    },
});
```

Tested with jQuery UI v1.11.

It's just plain awkward that this very basic feature has been broken for so long. Unfortunately, most of the jQuery bug reports don't offer an acceptable solution.

Comment: +1 on "...jQuery bug reports don't offer an acceptable solution". Its probably because now jQuery is becoming a legacy library and its team has moved on to some other project(s).

Comment: I like your answer. I would consider marking it as an answer if you could take care of 1 little bug still left. Correct the height of the content as well and let me know so that I can verify your solution. Thanks.

Comment: also using .css('width', 'unset') instead to avoid overflow when we have scroll bars etc.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes

Answer (score 3):

Based off of Khurram's solution, this is more robust, as it doesn't use magic numbers, but instead accounts for the paddings.

I also chose to do it on the `resize` event instead of `resizeStop`, as then it doesn't jump back and forth. [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6rr0myn/2/)

```
resize: function() {
  var heightPadding = parseInt($(this).css('padding-top'), 10) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'), 10),
    widthPadding = parseInt($(this).css('padding-left'), 10) + parseInt($(this).css('padding-right'), 10),
    titlebarMargin = parseInt($(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('margin-bottom'), 10);
  $(this).height($(this).parent().height() - $(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').outerHeight(true) - heightPadding - titlebarMargin);

  $(this).width($(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').outerWidth(true) - widthPadding);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

That css worked for me:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I had to add "box-sizing: border-box;"

Comment: it's make my dialog full screen.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following which is a result from the temporary solution from #10069 and it shows reducing or removing the default big padding can cause this issue.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content  {
    /* Fix resizing issue where content doesn't fit in the dialog anymore */
    padding: 3.5px;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar  {
    /* Adjust the titlebar so it is equal to the content fix */
    margin: 3.5px;
}
```